# Online Schema change when DB has existing triggers

Tags: mysql, mariadb, schema

I'm doing some due diligence before attempting a MariaDB schema change that really needs to be performed online, but seems like I'm going to have issues with the existing DB triggers in using a tool like [Percona online schema change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html), [Github gh-ost](https://github.com/github/gh-ost) and even Facebook's online schema change.  Are there any options that I am missing out there? Any resources to recommendations to minimize downtime?

Answer (score 1):

The Percona one is super tricky when it comes to triggers, and so I tried to use the GitHub tool mentioned by @HamoonDBA, but it looked more complicated than the Percona tool, so I rolled my own https://github.com/StirlingMarketingGroup/smg-live-alter

It's written with existing triggers in mind and keeping them intact, since in our own system, the triggers are ultra important

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are.

DB doesn't have any triggers. A table can has triggers.
If you want to alter the table which hasn't fulltext index maybe online DDL can help you.(It is implemented in MySQL/MariaDB)

But gh-ost is the best choose when you have triggers on the table.

Percona Online schema change and another tools such as oak-online-alter-table,soundcloud/lhm, facebook-osc are good when your table doesn't have any triggers. **But** in MariaDB 10.2 you can create multiple triggers for the same event So maybe they can work (I did not test)

Tools that maybe you didn't know:

https://github.com/soundcloud/lhm

https://github.com/shlomi-noach/openarkkit

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html